# datetime Mutator Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I want to transform the date fields that I have in mi database to show them in a different format.
In the database the date's fields are stored in a format 'y-m-d', but I want to show them in a format 'd-m-y'.
I did find a trait (torzer mutator), and that´s what I want but I need to know how to do that without to specify the column where I want to make the conversion, one way to detects automatically the columns that have date fields.

I know that maybe that not make sense, but my boss wants to reduce code in that aspect, unfortunately I haven't found anything similar.

```
<?php

use Torzer\Common\Traits\MapDateTimeMutator;

class MyClass extends Model {

use MapDateTimeMutator;

protected $mapDateTimeMutator = [
    'start_date' => ['from' => 'd/m/Y', 'to' => 'Y-m-d'],
    'finish_date' => ['from' => 'd/m/Y', 'to' => 'Y-m-d']
];

protected $dates = [
    'approved_at', 'start_date', 'finish_date'
];

...
```

that´s the way that Torzer mutator works.

Comment: Why don't you just {{ date('YOUR_FORMATE_SPECIFER',$date')  }} for displaying in blade, while NOT changing the default date structure in database ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro The columns added to the `$dates` property on a model are converted to Carbon instances so you don't need to use PHP's `date()`, you can just call the `format()` method on the property e.g. `{{ $model->start_date->format('d/m/y') }}`

Comment: ohhhk got it, thx

Comment: @RossWilson thanks bro, I´ll propose that, that works to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbon is a good library for this.

Also I don't know how you're setting your model up but my example is based off of laravel's documentation

```
Use Carbon\Carbon;

//where 'Date' = your attribute name
//so after you do something like a $m = model::find() and reference
//$m->date it will mutate it
public function getDateAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Carbon docs: 
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Any columns added to the `$dates` property on a model will be converted to carbon instances out-of-the-box.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about at all! I just thought I'd let you know :)